# How to call rest API in Python with requested form data using flask

Tags: python, flask, rest

Below is the **Python script**.

I have an HTML form with 3 fields: company, email and password. When the user submits the form I want to send those data as a request to another REST API and I am using below script.

I am getting 400 Bad Request Error after clicking on the submit button and I am not sure I am using the right approach. I am very new to Python. Could you please help me to get this done?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route('/') 
def student():
   return render_template('form.html')
    
@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])    
def result():
   url = "http://214.124.195.165/api/v1/users/sign-up"
   if request.method == 'POST':
       email = request.form.get('email')
       password = request.form.get('password')
        company = request.form.get('company')  
        json_data = { "email":email, "company": company, "password": password}
    
        headers = {'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
        response = requests.post(url, json_data, headers=headers)
        return response.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Below is the HTML code

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/result" method = "POST">
         <p>email <input type = "text" name = "email" /></p>
         <p>password <input type = "text" name = "password" /></p>
         <p>company <input type = "text" name = "company" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am getting below error:

```
error": "Bad Request",
"message": "JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'email': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'email': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 7]",
"path": "/user/sign-up",
"status": 400,
"timestamp": "2021-01-06T12:24:54.293+0000"
}
```

I want to send the submitted (company, email, password) data to an API using Python Flask. When I submit the form I am getting a 400 Bad Request. I am new to Python. Could you please help to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data in format

```
requests.post(url, json=json_data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: have you added json key also? in above snippet it doesnt have.

Comment: i added just now it Works Thank you so much Pritesh

Comment: in the same code i want to call another API with username and password to get token how to do that